# Xamarin test Cloud incompatibility issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I am running the test scripts for my app and I am getting the following error. 
Xamarin.UITest.dll version (1.3.8.0) and test-cloud.exe version (1.0.0.0) are incompatible

Any advise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a matching version `test-cloud.exe` within each `Xamarin.UITest.XXXXX` Nuget package and that is the `.exe` that you should use to run your tests with.

#### Example:

```
/packages/Xamarin.UITest.1.3.8.1491-dev
.
├── Xamarin.UITest-License.rtf
├── Xamarin.UITest.1.3.8.1491-dev.nupkg
├── lib
│   ├── Xamarin.UITest.dll
│   └── Xamarin.UITest.xml
└── tools
    └── test-cloud.exe

/packages/Xamarin.UITest.1.3.8
.
├── Xamarin.UITest-License.rtf
├── Xamarin.UITest.1.3.8.nupkg
├── lib
│   ├── Xamarin.UITest.dll
│   └── Xamarin.UITest.xml
└── tools
    └── test-cloud.exe
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply.

I am running the test scripts automatically through VSTS. As I am downloading the nugets, the nugets by default would be having the .exe file compatible with the downloaded Nuget, I am guessing. So why am I getting incompatibility issue ?

Comment: Are you using this task? https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/6842bfc286a8c179407e6bd813fc226a883f8c25/Tasks/XamarinTestCloud/task.json Also make sure the you are not setting the `test-cloud.exe Location` in your setup.. Ref: https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/test/xamarin-test-cloud

Comment: I observed one thing.

the package folder for my solution has Xamain.UITest of 1.0.0.0 and my UITest project had 1.3.8 version. Can you tell me how to push it to github ?

Comment: @azharali Are you storing the Nuget packages in your repo?

Comment: Yes. While running the script only the NuGets from my test projects are not being restored. I set the path for them in the .config file but still they are not being restored.

Comment: @azharali I would create another question with the details of your config and vsts/nuget restore issue (also adding in the VS team services tag).

Answer (score 0):

I observed one thing.

The package folder for my solution has Xamarin.UITest of 1.0.0.0 and my UITest project had 1.3.8 version. Can you tell me that how to push it to github ?